# Is it acceptable to make an acronym with a 'false' letter?

Tags: acronyms

(I don't know if this is the right place to ask this; if it's not please let me know.)

I want to name something with an acronym, and I found a very good word for it, but there is a word (in the meaning of the acronym) that starts with "n" and in my acronym the corresponding letter is "u". My idea is that the "u" is an "n" upside down (lowercase). I would like to use an acronym that is easy to pronounce and remember.

It would be complicated to describe my actual acronym, but as an example: let us suppose the meaning is "chocolate, oats and milk" (I am not feeling very creative at the moment) and I want to use the acronym "Cow" instead of "Com", using a "w" as if it was an "m" upside down.

My questions are:

1) Is this acceptable?

2) Are there other examples of "inexact" acronyms like mine?

3) Does this practice have a name?

Comment: It's going to be your creativity you can do anything, but in general it's not a **Linguistics** matter.

Comment: @adelrahimi Why not, the OP genuinely asks for linguistic aspect of limitations to such creativity. The other problem is that answers may appear to be language-specific.

Comment: Questions about "acceptability" are plainly not linguistic, they are marketing decisions. You would have to consult some compilation of trade names or something like that to see if anyone has ever used letter-rotation in constructing an acronym. There are no linguistic rules regarding acronym-formation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about branding not linguistics.